# select not common id from two table with common field name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

pager table

```
+----+-------------+
| id | content     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | bank        |
|  2 | invalid     |
|  3 | cat         |
+----+-------------+
```

page table

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| page_id   | content            |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  1        | people             |
|  3        | saved              |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

wanted result as

```
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
| id        |        content     | page_content  |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
|  3        | cat                | null          |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: can you explain what you want

Comment: need to select not equal id from the pager table assign values as dynamic in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.content, b.content AS page_content FROM page a JOIN pager b WHERE a.id = 3
```

The output will be:

```
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
| id        |        content     | page_content  |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
|  3        | cat                | saved         |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: if i have more than 20 values means how to all id

Comment: Not able to understand, what you want. Provide an example

Comment: in the same question assume that you don,t know the id for the data how to retrieve the value